# How do I get specific char from an array so that i can put into another array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

*im new to c++*
Basically I have been asked to write a program that asks for the first name initial, middle name initial and the whole of the surname and output the first name initial on one line, middle name initial on another and surname on another. I did one program at first but the input was't taken all in one line and im not sure how to do this, sorry if my explanation isn't very helpful.

*what i was asked to do*
Write a program to prompt the user to enter in a single line their first name initial, followed by a space, their middle name initial followed by a space and the entirety of their surname. Store this in a char array. 
 
The program should then output the first initial on one line, then the middle initial on a separate line and the surname on a line of its own. 
 
This program is to demonstrate the use of char arrays. Ensure that you complete this program using a char array and that the data input by the user is stored in a single char array. You can separate out the various parts of the name into separate arrays afterwards, but the initial read from the console should put the entirety of the input into a single char array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char firstNameInitial[2];
    char middleNameInitial[2];
    char surname[11];

cout << "Enter your first name initial: ";
cin >> firstNameInitial;
cout << "Enter your middle name initial: ";
cin >> middleNameInitial;
cout << "Enter your surname initial: ";
cin >> surname;

cout << firstNameInitial << endl << middleNameInitial << endl << surname << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

this is what i did at first but the input are on different lines how would i do it in 1 while having output in different

Comment: Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of how to use arrays, how to search them, how to copy parts of them to a different array, or somewhere else. Is there something specific in your C++ book, about this, that's unclear to you or you have a question about? "How do I do X", where "X" is something that's explained in every C++ book, is not really a good question for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Homework without work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get a specific char from an array so that I can put it into
>   another array?

This is how arrays are taught to beginners. Be thorough with the basics of arrays and usage of indexes to access the array elements and hence solve your problem. You can refer to [this](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/arrays) tutorial.

### Solution

You can solve your task in many ways. I will show you a solution using the [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) function. Moreover, you don't need any additional variables to separate the input. You can perform both read and display operations just by using a single array if you have some basic knowledge of array manipulation by now.

```
#include <iostream>

// Modify this according to your requirements
#define NAME_SIZE 30

int main() 
{
    // A single character array as per the constraints
    char name[NAME_SIZE];

    // Do it in the C-style!
    fgets(name, NAME_SIZE, stdin);

    // First initial
    std::cout << name[0] << '\n';

    // name[1] is the space that follows

    // Second initial
    std::cout << name[2] << '\n';

    // name[3] is the space that follows

    // Display the surname which starts at index 4
    // Remember that the string terminates with a null character
    for (unsigned i = 4; name[i] != '\0'; ++i) std::cout << name[i];

    // Success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have used your code on my program the surname comes up as its meant to if i change the unsigned i= 4 to i = 3 since 4 was making my first letter of surname not appear, but the first name initial and middle name initial comes out as blank.

Comment: @Bernardocosta Your problem statement says that the **initials are followed by a space**. Did you forget them while giving the input?

Comment: no i give the space. name[0] isnt taking in the first initial but taking a space in its place and name[2] is taking the second space, i manage to get the second initial with name[1] but then i cant get first initial either way

Comment: @Bernardocosta I can't make a conclusion by such a narrow description of this problem. Moreover, I had tested the code before submission. Ask a separate question **with the full code** that is causing this problem. I think you have some other code apart from the code that I gave you, or something is wrong with the input. So, don't forget to mention the input which is causing this error, and any other useful details that would assist me in diagnosing this problem for you. Please note that I won't be notified if you don't reply with the link of your new question.

Comment: ahh i just managed to fix it after what you said i had a cin >> name; which wasnt needed, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

What was required and is not is your current code (emphasize mine):

> ... prompt the user to enter **in a single line**...

Your current program uses 3 different prompts and most user will answer each element on its own line.

> Ensure [...] that the data input by the user is stored **in a single char array**.

You are using 3 distinct char arrays for the input.

Hint: to have line oriented input in C++, the key has name `getline`. And has you are required to only use char arrays, you should use `istream::getline`

```
constexpr int SIZE = 32;
...
char line[SIZE];
cout << "Enter first name initial, a space, middle name initial, a space and your last name\n";
cin.getline(line, SIZE);
...
```

There are then different ways to split the input line in 3 pieces. Here I will assume (and control) that input was as expected:

```
if ((line[0] == ' ') || (line[1] != ' ') || (line[2] == ' ') || (line[3] != ' ') {
    cerr << "Incorrect input" << endl;
    return 1;
}
char *firstinitial = line;
firstinitial[1] = '\0';            // ensure null termination
char *midinitial = line + 2
midinitial[1] = '\0';
char *lastname = line + 4;
for(char *ix = line; ix<line+SIZE; ix++) {   // ensure last name is null terminated
    if (*ix == '\n') {
        *ix = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
line[line+SIZE-1] = '\0'                     // if SIZE characters were read
cout << "First name initial is: " << firstinitial << '\n';
cout << "Middle name initial is: " << midinitial << '\n';
cout << "Last name is: " << lastname<< '\n';
```